# Waiting for NSURLConnection delegates to finish

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have the following sequence:

1. Start MBProgressHUD spinner
2. Download several images using NSConnectionURL and implemented connectionDidFinishLoading delegate to show the image
3. Stop spinner after all images are downloaded and show the parent view that contains all the images

How should I implement the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` to determine whether all the images are downloaded so that I can stop the spinner?

Should I be tracking the number of downloads, but what about thread safety?

Or should I be looking at GCD?

Comment: Following the number of total and completed downloads is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an `NSOperationQueue` and submit the downloads as individual block operations with synchronous `NSURLConnection` requests. You can set the maximum number of concurrent operations there, so that you don’t download everything at once, and you get cancelling for free. Tracking the finish can be done simply by submitting another operation to the queue – the last operation submitted will run after all downloads have finished. This would probably require limiting the number of concurrent operations to one, though, so an alternative is to watch (KVO) the number of remaining operations. When that drops to zero, you’re done.

Comment: Found this http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/. Useful readup.

Comment: Yes, that’s close to what I had in mind. Only I wouldn’t bother with subclassing `NSOperation`, since you can easily create the download operation using `-addOperationWithBlock:` and synchronous `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I implement the connectionDidFinishLoading: to determine
>   whether all the images are downloaded so that I can stop the spinner?

I'd do it by keeping track of the number of active connections. You could keep the connections themselves in a mutable array and remove them as they complete, or just increment a counter when a connection starts and decrement it when they finish. Either way, when the number of active connections reaches zero, you remove the spinner.